# NSJSONSerialization fails to parse due to backslashes

Tags: ios, json, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

The original text in the database is `stuff stuff :o\`.

My PHP server API is grabbing that and putting it into a json payload as this key:value pair:

```
"notetext": "stuff stuff :o\\",
```

My iOS objective-c code fetches the output of the server API with an `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

I parse the `NSData` object provided by the `NSURLSessionDataTask` like this:

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

I get the error: `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

If I remove the backslash from the original text so that it is `stuff stuff :o` then everything works as expected. So the backslash at the end of the string seems to be causing my problem. But it looks like it is being escaped properly.

What am I missing? How do I make sure this can get parsed properly?

Comment: Not sure but did you try to see if can work with 4 backslash ?

Comment: Try this approach in PHP $payload = array(
    "notetext" => "stuff stuff :o\\"
);
$jsonPayload = json_encode($payload);

Comment: @PtitXav That's the thing, I'm not adding the backslashes myself. The `json_encode()` PHP function is doing that... but it shouldn't need to add 4 backslashes. The original text only includes one backslash, so backslashing that should be all that is needed. But when iOS is json decoding... it seems like it's doing it wrong and applying the backslash to the structural quote mark.

Comment: @UmerKhan No, that's not how this is working. The text `:o\` is in my database. I'm reading that value out of the db and then json encoding that and sending it to the app. It correctly encodes it as `:o\\`, but iOS seems to be wrongly decoding it.